# Javascript: Error, object is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a strange issue with this very small code :

```
function autre(element)
{
    if (element.value=="autre") 
    {
        var inputText=document.createElement("input");
        inputText.setAttribute("type", "text");
        inputText.setAttribute("name", "autre");
        inputText.setAttribute("required", "");
        element.parentNode.appendChild(inputText);      
    }
    else element.parentNode.removeChild(element.nextSibling);
}
```

and HTML

```
<select name="matiere" onchange="autre(this);">
    <option value="autre">Autre</option>
    <option value="...">Some others options</option>
</select>
```

Wich create an input text when the 'autre' value of a select is selected.. This works fine.. But when I change the value again I get a weird error: object is not a function..

Any idea ?..

**Edit :** The problem was as ceakki mentionned the name of the function. Thanks!
Thank you everybody for your help

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with this code. Can you tell us what line it's occurring on?

Comment: Tested on FF and Chrome and no error occurred, keeps adding and removing inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of the **autre()** function or of the new created element **<input name="autre" ... />**.

It seems that IE9 appends the name **autre** of the <input name="autre" ... /> to the current Window object (or global object).

In this case **autre** will refer to the new created element and not to your function.

Answer (score 1):

That script works well for me http://jsfiddle.net/J7acJ/

Just added an eventListener

```
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener('change', function(){
    autre(this);
})
```

Comment: This code will not work in older IE versions. Also, his error is because the window.autre is replaced by the new created element having the name "autre". That's why the error says: object is not a function.